# jQuery Change json data in cookie

Tags: jquery, json, cookies

I'm setting a cookie that stores some of my JSON data. Something along the lines of:

```
$.cookie('user-info', JSON.stringify(locationInfo));
```

So the cookie value looks something like:

```
{"city":"New York","state":"NY","zip":"90210"}
```

How would I go about simply changing the "zip" value so instead of 90210 I want it to 
be 10101. I tried something along the lines of:

```
$.cookie('user-info', { zip: '10101' });
```

But this doesn't seem to be updating anything. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to recreate the cookie completely, you can't change just 1 property like that because it's a string, not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
var cookieObj = $.parseJSON($.cookie('user-info')); //might be done automatically, not sure
cookieObj.zip = 10101;
$.cookie('user-info', JSON.stringify(cookieObj));
```

Comment: Thank you @tymeJV your a lifesaver!